# Apache2 remove response headers

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have been going crazy trying to remove response headers from my Apache2 server.  I have mod_headers enabled and I have 'Header unset BLAH_HEADER_NAME' in my apache2.conf file, but it doesn't appear to be working, though 'Header append' appears to work..go figure.

I've read that mod_perl might work, but I don't have any experience doing this..any ideas.  I also read that 'Header unset' might be bugged, is this confirmed.

Comment: Which header are you trying to modify?

Comment: i'm trying to remove: Header unset Content-Length
    Header unset Keep-Alive
    Header unset Content-Type
    Header unset Server

Comment: i have ServerTokens Prod and ServerSignature Off, so in my Header unset Server, i'm just trying to remove the whole header in the response.  i was given specs to have a minimalist response header to lighten the responses.

Answer (score 4):

I can't really imagine why you'd want to unset all of those, breaking your compliance with the HTTP/1.1 standard.. but, `Server` cannot be unset (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026)), while the others ought to work; try:

```
Header always unset Content-Length
Header onsuccess unset Content-Length
```

Comment: this actually didn't work this is what i have in my apache2.conf on ubuntu 11.10 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always unset Content-Length
    Header onsuccess unset Content-Length
    Header always unset Keep-Alive
    Header always unset Content-Type
    Header onsuccess unset Content-Type
</IfModule> i definitely appreciate the help!!

Comment: this addition is at the bottom of my conf file after everything is loaded..fyi.